# java.lang.AssertionError: Status Expected :200 Actual :400

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I have an authentication controller with the following endpoint

```
   @PostMapping("/register")
   fun register(@RequestBody body: RegisterDto): ResponseEntity<User> {
     val user = User()
     user.name = body.name
     user.email = body.email
     user.password = body.password
     return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(userService.saveUser(user))
  }
```

Now I have written a test case for the above snippet as shown bellow

```
  fun `register user with valid input, returns ok`() {
    val result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/auth/register")
        .param("id","1")
        .param("name","Homer")
        .param("email","homer@simpsons.com")
        .param("password","123456")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
}
```

On running, I get 400, and I need to get 200 (successful). I'm quite new to testing on spring boots. What could I be doing wrong or missing? Thanks in andvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the params. Actually, You need to pass a JSON body as below:

```kotlin
fun `register user with valid input, returns ok` () {
  val user = User()
  user.id = 1
  user.name = "Homer"
  user.email = "homer@simpsons.com"
  user.password = "123456"

  var response = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)
  val result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/auth/register")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(response)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
  result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated)
}
```